# Directory change monitoring; distinguish between change of content and attributes

Tags: winapi

Well, the heading says all ...
For an application I need to register the types of changes in directories.
For this I use ReadDirectoryChangesW. In the retrieved FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION
I get only one type of action for changes of content and attributes: FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED.
But I need to distinguish between them.
But how?
The only way I see is to create 2 monitor processes, both with ReadDirectoryChangesW which
differ in the notifyFilter (one with/ one without FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES),
and after that comparing the monitored lists etc.
This seems quite costly to me.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Check the file attributes and content yourself?

Comment: Look into the NTFS transaction log if something changed for the nature of the change?

Comment: Checking the file attributes/ contents myself would help only if I had the status before transaction, which I don't have. NTFS transaction log is not used/ present.

Comment: Um, ReadDirectoryChanges doesn't detect changes in content. It detects changes to the directory. You can infer content changes from directory changes (e.g., if the last-write-time changed, then probably there was a content change) but it's not a guarantee. For example, file contents can change without changing the last-write-time.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But a changed last-write-time is sufficient for me to take as a "content change".
The problem is if only the attributes are changed. I won't take that as a content change.

Comment: To be more specific to my first comment:
Keeping file info in an own database wouldn't help, as for disinguishing change of attribute and content
I would have to compute the content's hash, which is much too costly.
Using the USN journal would do the job, but with that the whole volume would be journaled, which might be
costly too.

Comment: Wait a minute:
I thought that every kind of content changing would result in a changed last-write-time.
But - of course - not every changed last-write-time means that the contents has changed.
The first is not right?

Comment: `to create 2 monitor processes` - really you need implement one class, which take `dwNotifyFilter` as parameter and monitor changes. and create 2 instances of this class with `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES` and `FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK & ~FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES` for example.. this is same costly compare one class instance

Comment: `every kind of content changing would result in a changed last-write-time` - this is not true. if you map file (with write access) and modify map - will be content change without time change

Comment: Thank you for the info about file maps. But concerning you proposal I think this will create 2 monitoring threads. This is the first costly thing. And then, after monitoring, I will have to compare the lists to distinguish content/ attribute change, even more costly. This is would I want to avoid.

Comment: no, you not need create 2 threads - you need asynchronous handles + `BindIoCompletionCallback` - 2 or 1 file handle with this - not big different. about compare lists - yes, here can some problems, but i not understand your final target and hard say are need compare or process separately

Comment: and now i check - in case file will be modified by using file mapping - you not got any notification about this at all. so with `ReadDirectoryChangesW` you can not reliable monitor changed in content of files

Comment: I'll follow you hints - thank you.

Comment: so only minifilter driver can monitor changes to file by mapping (paging io)

Comment: Another way content can change without a last-modified change is if somebody uses `SetFileTime` to explicitly suppress updating the last-modified time: "To prevent file operations using the given handle from modifying the last access time, call SetFileTime immediately after opening the file handle and pass a FILETIME structure that has both the dwLowDateTime and dwHighDateTime members set to 0xFFFFFFFF."

Comment: C++ and C are very different. Please pick one. If your code uses both, you're probably really using C++, but in some places not using all of its features.